# Python regex solution

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the **Required string** from **Actual logset** using the **python code**. But am getting slashes as shown in **current output** any suggestion are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Actual Logset**

```
[{'logStreamName': '2018/05/15/[$LATEST]e9c838560b4a43a8beab55c09b8cff61', 'timestamp': 1526397147847, 'message': 'START RequestId: 614b56e6-5852-11e8-a3d4-850c17ee5197 Version: $LATEST\n', 'ingestionTime': 1526397148010, 'eventId': '34039793865899822940373036294062893091972474685247389696'}, {'logStreamName': '2018/05/15/[$LATEST]e9c838560b4a43a8beab55c09b8cff61', 'timestamp': 1526397148227, 'message': "Ec2 Instances which are stopped:  Instance ID:  i-006690f105487930f Instance state:  {'Code': 80, 'Name': 'stopped'} Instance type:  t2.micro\n", 'ingestionTime': 1526397148215, 'eventId': '34039793874374106115814673088093836532895101688702042112'}]
```

**Python code:**

```
regex1 = r"Ec2 Instances.*micro"
Strres = str(logset) # Logset is a list which has logs
matches1 = re.findall(regex1,str(Strres))
print(matches1)
```

**Required String**

```
"Ec2 Instances which are stopped:  Instance ID:  i-006690f105487930f Instance state:  {'Code': 80, 'Name': 'stopped'} Instance type:  t2.micro"
```

When I execute the above code, I get following output, not sure why so many slashes are included after performing regex operation.

**Current Output**

```
['Ec2 Instances which are stopped:  Instance ID:  i-0ab4e087422860879 Instance state:  {\'Code\': 80, \'Name\': \'stopped\'} Instance type:  t2.micro\
", "Ec2 Instances which are stopped:  Instance ID:  i-03849720b1537c31c Instance state:  {\'Code\': 80, \'Name\': \'stopped\'} Instance type:  t2.micro\
", "Ec2 Instances which are running:  Instance ID:  i-006690f105487930f Instance state:  {\'Code\': 16, \'Name\': \'running\'} Instance type:  t2.micro\
", \'END RequestId: 7fcacec8-59aa-11e8-9ce2-fbf81c0889df\
\', \'REPORT RequestId: 7fcacec8-59aa-11e8-9ce2-fbf81c0889df\\tDuration: 717.44 ms\\tBilled Duration: 800 ms \\tMemory Size: 128 MB\\tMax Memory Used: 39 MB\\t\
\', \'START RequestId: 27dc0e69-59ac-11e8-805d-7134bbe0f1d1 Version: $LATEST\
\', "Ec2 Instances which are stopped:  Instance ID:  i-006690f105487930f Instance state:  {\'Code\': 80, \'Name\': \'stopped\'} Instance type:  t2.micro\
", "Ec2 Instances which are stopped:  Instance ID:  i-0ab4e087422860879 Instance state:  {\'Code\': 80, \'Name\': \'stopped\'} Instance type:  t2.micro\
", "Ec2 Instances which are stopped:  Instance ID:  i-03849720b1537c31c Instance state:  {\'Code\': 80, \'Name\': \'stopped\'} Instance type:  t2.micro']
```

Comment: And what do you see if you replace `print(matches1)` with `for m in matches1: print(m)`?

Comment: why my question is downvoted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @zwer you can treat the logset as list of dict :

```
import re
logset = [{'logStreamName': '2018/05/15/[$LATEST]e9c838560b4a43a8beab55c09b8cff61', 'timestamp': 1526397147847, 'message': 'START RequestId: 614b56e6-5852-11e8-a3d4-850c17ee5197 Version: $LATEST\n', 'ingestionTime': 1526397148010, 'eventId': '34039793865899822940373036294062893091972474685247389696'}, {'logStreamName': '2018/05/15/[$LATEST]e9c838560b4a43a8beab55c09b8cff61', 'timestamp': 1526397148227, 'message': "Ec2 Instances which are stopped:  Instance ID:  i-006690f105487930f Instance state:  {'Code': 80, 'Name': 'stopped'} Instance type:  t2.micro\n", 'ingestionTime': 1526397148215, 'eventId': '34039793874374106115814673088093836532895101688702042112'}]

regex = "Ec2 Instances.*micro"
res = [e["message"] for e in logset if re.match(regex, e["message"])]
print(res)
```

Output :

> ["Ec2 Instances which are stopped:  Instance ID:  i-006690f105487930f Instance state:  {'Code': 80, 'Name': 'stopped'} Instance type:  t2.micro\n"]